# how to visualize the Tensorflow model of Text-to-speech synthesis https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2

Tags: matplotlib, pytorch, text-to-speech, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I have been trying to visualize and see layers/parameters/Flops for this Tensorflow model of Text-to-speech synthesis https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2

- Is there a way I can visualize or see graph of Tacotron-2 with all its RNN/LSTM layers using tensorflow?
- Do I need train the model first before being able to print the model, or is there a way to simply see what ops are in each layer for the model without training?

I'm having a hard time figuring this out as I'm new to TF/pytorch frameworks. It seems to me one should be able to just print the model as the github has .py source, but I just don't know how this simple/basic things work with python and how to do it.

Comment: you can try Netron.

Comment: what is it, and how do I specify this github tacotron-2 model to it? I'm very new to ML/python.